# can't get second number between parenthesis using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

now I begin learning regex, and I have set of string in format like "(9/13)", and I need get second number. I  try this regex: `/\(.*?[^\d]*(\d+?)\)/g`, in [online regex](https://regex101.com/r/mFGYcA/2) it works normally.

But here:

```
var d = "(9/13)";
var v = /\(.*?[^\d]*(\d+?)\)/g;
alert(d.match(v));
```

it returns "(9/13)" , what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You really could just use https://regex101.com/r/mFGYcA/2/codegen?language=javascript and keep only what you need. If you are using regex101, use all of its power.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const source = "(9/13)";

const re = /\/(\d+)\)/;

console.log('result', re.exec(source).pop())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Regex.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to find the number

```js
const source = "(9/13)";

const re = /\(\d+\/(\d+)\)/;

console.log(re.exec(source)[1])
```